# How can i scan Bar code Android based scanner using Jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, barcode-scanner

I am working on android browser based scanning (Zebra scanner) functionality. I have only one textbox field in UI screen. The Textbox accepts only 250 char to 280 char. If you scan barcode, textbox will fill and call api service. I wrote the service call but How can i write the scanning functionality using jQuery. Can anyone give me idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your requirements?  Is a form submit ok?  Is ajax required?  Conceptually you'd attach an `input` or `change` event to the input element and either submit a form or perform an ajax call to the service endpoint.  Or if you want the users to hit a button to send the request, that would be a slight caveat.

Comment: after scan immediately fire the function (call service). no change or text box key press and no button click.

Comment: Then the `input` event is probably what you are after.  `input` is the same as `change`, but it does not wait for a blur event.  It happens any time the value of the input changes.